# how to sort python dict by its value?

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

Initially data is this:

```
dict = {<User: user2>: {'diff': 48, 'alike': 1}, <User: user3>: {'diff': 42, 'alike': 2}, <User: user4>: {'diff': 45, 'alike': 1}, <User: user5>: {'diff': 43, 'alike':
 2}, <User: user6>: {'diff': 46, 'alike': 1}, <User: user7>: {'diff': 46, 'alike': 1}, <User: user8>: {'diff': 49, 'alike': 1}, <User: user9>: {'diff': 50, 'ali
ke': 0}, <User: user10>: {'diff': 46, 'alike': 1}, <User: user11>: {'diff': 37, 'alike': 3}, <User: user12>: {'diff': 50, 'alike': 0}, <User: user13>: {'diff':
50, 'alike': 0}, <User: user14>: {'diff': 50, 'alike': 0}, <User: user15>: {'diff': 50, 'alike': 0}, <User: user16>: {'diff': 50, 'alike': 0}, <User: user17>: {
'diff': 50, 'alike': 0}, <User: user18>: {'diff': 50, 'alike': 0}, <User: user19>: {'diff': 50, 'alike': 0}, <User: user20>: {'diff': 50, 'alike': 0}}
```

Then I sort it:

```
sorted(dict) == [{'diff': 50, 'alike': 0}, {'diff': 50, 'alike': 0}, {'diff': 50, 'alike': 0}, {'diff': 50, 'alike': 0}, {'diff': 50, 'alike': 0}, {'diff': 50, 'alike': 0}, {'d
    iff': 50, 'alike': 0}, {'diff': 50, 'alike': 0}, {'diff': 50, 'alike': 0}, {'diff': 50, 'alike': 0}, {'diff': 45, 'alike': 1}, {'diff': 46, 'alike': 1}, {'diff'
    : 46, 'alike': 1}, {'diff': 46, 'alike': 1}, {'diff': 48, 'alike': 1}, {'diff': 49, 'alike': 1}, {'diff': 42, 'alike': 2}, {'diff': 43, 'alike': 2}, {'diff': 37
    , 'alike': 3}]
```

How do I sort it by "diff"?

Comment: That's not a `dict`, that's a list of dicts.

Comment: @Lattyware it start off as a dict, then i used sorted(dict), and i get that result

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For one, you are not sorting a `dict` - you are sorting a list of `dicts` - these are very different things, not least as a `dict` in Python has no defined order.

You can do this easily with [`sorted()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sorted) and [`operator.itemgetter()`](http://docs.python.org/library/operator.html):

```
import operator
sorted_dicts = sorted(dicts, key=operator.itemgetter("diff"))
```

The `sorted()` builtin takes the `key` keyword argument, which is a function which takes the value, and gives another value to sort on. Here we use an `itemgetter()` to get the desired value from the `dict` to sort by.

## Edit:

Given your change, there are two answers, as you are being unclear. If you want the list of values, it's simply a case of extracting them from your original `dict`:

```
sorted(users.values(), key=operator.itemgetter("diff"))
```

Which is as simple as taking `dict.values()`. Naturally, under Python 2.x, you will want to use `viewitems()` or `iteritems()` for good performance.

If you want to sort the `dict` itself, it's a different matter, as `dict`s (as I stated) are inherently unordered.

First of all, I would like to note that `sorted(dict)` does not produce the output you suggested - a dict iterates over the keys, not the values by default:

```
users = {
    '<User: user10>': {'alike': 1, 'diff': 46},
    '<User: user11>': {'alike': 3, 'diff': 37},
    '<User: user12>': {'alike': 0, 'diff': 50},
    '<User: user13>': {'alike': 0, 'diff': 50},
    '<User: user14>': {'alike': 0, 'diff': 50},
    '<User: user15>': {'alike': 0, 'diff': 50},
    '<User: user16>': {'alike': 0, 'diff': 50},
    '<User: user17>': {'alike': 0, 'diff': 50},
    '<User: user18>': {'alike': 0, 'diff': 50},
    '<User: user19>': {'alike': 0, 'diff': 50},
    '<User: user20>': {'alike': 0, 'diff': 50},
    '<User: user2>': {'alike': 1, 'diff': 48},
    '<User: user3>': {'alike': 2, 'diff': 42},
    '<User: user4>': {'alike': 1, 'diff': 45},
    '<User: user5>': {'alike': 2, 'diff': 43},
    '<User: user6>': {'alike': 1, 'diff': 46},
    '<User: user7>': {'alike': 1, 'diff': 46},
    '<User: user8>': {'alike': 1, 'diff': 49},
    '<User: user9>': {'alike': 0, 'diff': 50}
}

print(sorted(users))
```

Gives us:

```
['<User: user10>', '<User: user11>', '<User: user12>', '<User: user13>', '<User: user14>', '<User: user15>', '<User: user16>', '<User: user17>', '<User: user18>', '<User: user19>', '<User: user20>', '<User: user2>', '<User: user3>', '<User: user4>', '<User: user5>', '<User: user6>', '<User: user7>', '<User: user8>', '<User: user9>']
```

To produce a sorted `dict`, we need to use [`collections.OrderedDict()`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict):

```
import collections

users = {
    '<User: user10>': {'alike': 1, 'diff': 46},
    '<User: user11>': {'alike': 3, 'diff': 37},
    '<User: user12>': {'alike': 0, 'diff': 50},
    '<User: user13>': {'alike': 0, 'diff': 50},
    '<User: user14>': {'alike': 0, 'diff': 50},
    '<User: user15>': {'alike': 0, 'diff': 50},
    '<User: user16>': {'alike': 0, 'diff': 50},
    '<User: user17>': {'alike': 0, 'diff': 50},
    '<User: user18>': {'alike': 0, 'diff': 50},
    '<User: user19>': {'alike': 0, 'diff': 50},
    '<User: user20>': {'alike': 0, 'diff': 50},
    '<User: user2>': {'alike': 1, 'diff': 48},
    '<User: user3>': {'alike': 2, 'diff': 42},
    '<User: user4>': {'alike': 1, 'diff': 45},
    '<User: user5>': {'alike': 2, 'diff': 43},
    '<User: user6>': {'alike': 1, 'diff': 46},
    '<User: user7>': {'alike': 1, 'diff': 46},
    '<User: user8>': {'alike': 1, 'diff': 49},
    '<User: user9>': {'alike': 0, 'diff': 50}
}

print(collections.OrderedDict(sorted(users.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]["diff"])))
```

Which gives us:

```
OrderedDict([('<User: user11>', {'diff': 37, 'alike': 3}), ('<User: user3>', {'diff': 42, 'alike': 2}), ('<User: user5>', {'diff': 43, 'alike': 2}), ('<User: user4>', {'diff': 45, 'alike': 1}), ('<User: user10>', {'diff': 46, 'alike': 1}), ('<User: user7>', {'diff': 46, 'alike': 1}), ('<User: user6>', {'diff': 46, 'alike': 1}), ('<User: user2>', {'diff': 48, 'alike': 1}), ('<User: user8>', {'diff': 49, 'alike': 1}), ('<User: user20>', {'diff': 50, 'alike': 0}), ('<User: user9>', {'diff': 50, 'alike': 0}), ('<User: user13>', {'diff': 50, 'alike': 0}), ('<User: user19>', {'diff': 50, 'alike': 0}), ('<User: user12>', {'diff': 50, 'alike': 0}), ('<User: user18>', {'diff': 50, 'alike': 0}), ('<User: user15>', {'diff': 50, 'alike': 0}), ('<User: user14>', {'diff': 50, 'alike': 0}), ('<User: user17>', {'diff': 50, 'alike': 0}), ('<User: user16>', {'diff': 50, 'alike': 0})])
```

Note that here we had to use a `lambda` statement for the key argument, as an `itemgetter()` unfortunately can't get multiple levels of items for us.

Comment: I tried to fix it myself and forgot that edits had to be >6 chars. Anyway +1

Comment: please check my stuff again, i added some more details... thank you!

Comment: @yaojiang I'll update the answer this time, but please don't update the question after people have given answers. Give an example that actually fits what you want at the beginning - it's rude to do otherwise.

Comment: @Lattyware sorry! will keep that in mind next time, thank you!

Answer (score 5):

```
sorted(your_list, key=lambda el: el["diff"])
```

The `key` keyword argument should be a function that takes an element of the list you are sorting and returns the value that should be used in the sort comparison.  `lambda` is shorthand for `def` - that is, it defines a function (with several limitations).  The same line could be written this way:

```
def get_key(el):
    return el["diff"]

sorted(your_list, key=get_key)
```

Comment: @agf - absolutely!  Explanation added!

Comment: please check my stuff again, i added some more details... thank you!